# LinkedIn Marketing developer plattform APIs, how to use access token?

Tags: linkedin-api

After receiving the access token trough the 3-legged OAuth (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin%2Fmarketing%2Fcontext&tabs=HTTPS), how can I use this access token for API requests?

For example if I want to get the follower statistics of my company, where would i put the access token in this API request?

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityFollowerStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity={organization URN}
```

I could not find it in the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/follower-statistics?tabs=http

Answer (score 1):

I had to press on the "curl" tab under "Sample request" in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/follower-statistics?tabs=http

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).